# How to integrate getstream in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, getstream-io

How to integrate getstream.io in laravel 5.3. How to integrate it with laravel eloquent? Please provide me details documentation of it.

Answer (score 0):

We document the usage of the Stream-Laravel SDK here: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-laravel/blob/master/README.md

There are instructions there for setting up the configuration, names of your feeds, and details of how to extend your Eloquent models.

If you have a more specific integration question we're happy to answer it as well.